# Finding same equivalence classes for $(x,y) \in R \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, relations, equivalence-relations

Question:

Consider the following equivalence relation on the real numbers:

$(x,y) \in R \iff x-y \in \mathbb{Z}$

In the following list of equivalence classes find two equivalence classes that are equal.

$[-5],\  [\frac{8}{3}], \ [\frac{-2}{6}], [\frac{4}{3}], [\frac{1}{6}] $

My attempt:

Notice that $ \frac{-1}{3} \in [\frac{8}{3}], [\frac{-2}{6}] $.

Can we conclude that $[\frac{8}{3}], \ [\frac{-2}{6}]$ are equal? In general if I can find one common element that is in two equivalence classes would that imply they are equal? I think there is a theorem that states that two equivalence classes have nothing in common or are equal.

Comment: Yes, always either $[a] = [b]$ or $[a] \cap [b] = \varnothing$.

Comment: Correct. Equivalence classes form a partition. Next to what you already mentioned: they are never empty.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any $r\in\Bbb R$ ,$r\in$ $[ fractional$ $part$ $(x)]$.i.e.$r_1$ and $r_2$ are in same equivalence class iff they have the same fractional part. Now compute fractional parts of the given numbers and the conclusion follows